Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/signup", null) in the _WidgetsAppState
I can't solve a problem with "Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/signup", null) in the _WidgetsAppState." Here is the code:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';
import 'package:mymarks_app/services/snack_bar.dart' as service;
import 'package:mymarks_app/screens/home_screen.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool isHiddenPassword = true;
  final emailTextInputController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordTextInputController = TextEditingController();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailTextInputController.dispose();
    passwordTextInputController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void togglePasswordView() {
    setState(() {
      isHiddenPassword = !isHiddenPassword;
    });
  }

  Future<void> login() async {
    if (!formKey.currentState!.validate()) return;

    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/login'),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: json.encode({
          'username': emailTextInputController.text.trim(),
          'password': passwordTextInputController.text.trim(),
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        if (responseData['message'] == 'Успешный вход!') {
          if (mounted) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => HomeScreen(
                  userData: responseData,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        } else {
          if (mounted) {
            service.SnackBarService.showSnackBar(
              context,
              'Неправильный username или пароль. Повторите попытку',
              true,
            );
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (mounted) {
          service.SnackBarService.showSnackBar(
            context,
            'Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса: ${response.statusCode}',
            true,
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (mounted) {
        service.SnackBarService.showSnackBar(
          context,
          'Произошла ошибка: ${e.toString()}',
          true,
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Войти'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                autocorrect: false,
                controller: emailTextInputController,
                validator: (email) =>
                    email != null && !EmailValidator.validate(email)
                        ? 'Введите правильный Email'
                        : null,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Введите Email',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              TextFormField(
                autocorrect: false,
                controller: passwordTextInputController,
                obscureText: isHiddenPassword,
                validator: (value) => value != null && value.length < 6
                    ? 'Минимум 6 символов'
                    : null,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Введите пароль',
                  suffix: InkWell(
                    onTap: togglePasswordView,
                    child: Icon(
                      isHiddenPassword
                          ? Icons.visibility_off
                          : Icons.visibility,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: login,
                child: const Center(child: Text('Войти')),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/signup'),
                child: const Text(
                  'Регистрация',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () =>
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/reset_password'),
                child: const Text('Сбросить пароль'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

That code is login_screen.dart . Here is my routes:
routes: {
        '/': (context) => const MainScreen(),
        '/account': (context) => const AccScreen(),
        '/login': (context) => const LoginScreen(),
        '/signup': (context) => const SignUpScreen(),
        '/reset_password': (context) => const ResetPasswordScreen(),
        '/verify_email': (context) => const VerifyEmailScreen(),
        '/homepage': (context) => const HomeScreen(),
        '/tlogin': (context) => const TeacherLogin(),
        '/tsignup': (context) => const TeacherSignup(),
        '/admin_screen': (context) => const AdminScreen(),
        '/notauth': (context) => NotAuthScreen(),
      },
      onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Page Not Found')),
            body: const Center(child: Text('404: Page not found')),
          ),
        );
      },
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }
}

Please help me!
I'm expecting to redirect to my signup_screen.dart and I tried some other solves to the questions on stackoverflow.

Hope you have wrapped routes in MaterialApp rest other code is working I tried it, You have to restart app and check again.

Yeah I wrapped those in MaterialApp. Also, my other navigators are working.
